# Make (No Targets specified)

Tags: gcc, cmake

Hi i am trying to use cmake with visual studio 2015 and following a tutorial https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/getting-started.

It works well my files are generated and transferred to build folder but after that [>make] commands gives an error that [make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop]

Although i am using right generator visual studio 2014. I have gcc and mingw64 installed and paths are also set but i still get this error. If someone can help i will be thankfull

Comment: "I am using right generator visual studio 2014" - So CMake creates a **solution** file, not a *Makefile*. Just open the solution file in Visual Studio and proceed building.  See also that question for more info about using CMake with Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437481/cmake-and-visual-studio

Comment: sorry for late reply but thanks i will try it